# How can I interrupt apt-get upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade

I just started `apt-get upgrade` which downloads

```
http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20180508.1.orig.tar.gz
```

This is currently super slow. Downloading those 30MB from archive.canonical.com is estimated to take more than 1h.

Can I interrupt it and stop it from downloading it?

### What I tried

```
kill PID
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But now `dpkg` want to install that package ...

Comment: what about `sudo apt remove adobe-flashplugin` or whatever the name of the package is. Just remove it.

Comment: Well, before I can run any apt command I have to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fix the interruption, right? And `dpkg --configure -a` will start the slow download again...

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/253925/250300, https://askubuntu.com/q/803569/250300

Comment: In regard to `adobe-flashplugin_20180508.1.orig.tar.gz`: My update eventually - after several minutes - downloaded the file. In your case, might it not be worth waiting?